# Can Cellulose Molecules be Synthesized from Glucose?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, carbohydrates

I am reading that cellulose may be broken down into glucose. This is usually done with some sort of solvent.

Is there any way to 'rebuild' these cellulose molecules from glucose?

Comment: Are you interested in a lab synthesis (in a flask) or the biosynthesis?  Cellulose is biosynthetically derived from glucose derivatives

Answer (score 4):

Cellulose may be broken into smaller pieces (though not necessarily into separate glucose molecules) and regenerated into [cellophane with the viscose process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscose).

For the home lab, rather than using the poisonous and *extremely* flammable $\ce{CS2}$ in the viscose process, the *somewhat* safer [cuprammonium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuprammonium_rayon) process is a better choice. Do be careful -- don't wind up with blue stains on skin or clothing, it shows poor technique. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvoimHLHdnA) for a demonstration.